# Java Swing: Component with 50% alpha hiding elements behind it entirely in JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I want to display a grid over a background image. For this, I'm using a JLayeredPane. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
JLayeredPane layers = new JLayeredPane();
layers.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE ) );
layers.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

BufferedImage backgroundImage = null;
            try{ backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/Background.png"));}
            catch(IOException ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            }

JLabel bImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(backgroundImage));
JPanel grid = createGrid(); //creates a grid the same size as the image (500,500)

grid.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,125));

layers.add(bImage, new Integer(1));
layers.add(grid, new Integer(2));
```

What is then displayed is the Grid, in black 50% alpha, on top of the frame background, and the background image is nowhere to be seen.

If I comment out

```
//layers.add(grid, new Integer(2));
```

I can see the image, so I know it's there.

How would I go about showing the grid over the image?

Thanks,

Comment: After some more testing, it seems that it's caused by the FlowLayout. The image is actually beneath the grid, (as in, a higher y value). Is there any way to actually overlay them? I tried different Layouts, but each one seems to have its own problems.

Comment: Hmm, getting there. I added a setBounds and removed the FlowLayout, Now I can see both of them only if they are not at exactly the same bounds, even 1 pixel is enough, then it works. Does anybody know why that happens?

Comment: Post your `SSCCE` demonstrating the problem.